# when I press enter on suggestions on vscode it shows an error "command 'extension.insertColonOrSemiColon' not found"?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, styled-components, web-development-server

[image]
VSCODE show `command 'extension.insertColonOrSemiColon' not found` warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing **vscode-styled-components** extension from my VSCode fixed the problem for me :)

Comment: This was the case for me as well. I am running node version 16.15.1 and the version of the styled components extension was v1.7.4.